# Create SQL query based on several records?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I would like to get an SQL Query which gives me an overview of closed Service Requests. This based on the tasks of that Service Request.
Several forums could not help :-(

My Table: ServiceRequestTasks

SRNr | TaskNr | TaskDescr | TaskCreationDate | InfoRecDate
0001 | T00000 | Start_____ |1/01/2018
0001 | T00001 | SD2C____ | 2/01/2018_______| 4/01/2019
0001 | T00002 | D________ | 5/01/2019
0001 | T00003 | RAI______ | 6/01/2019_______| 12/01/2019
0001 | T00004 | SCR_____ | 15/01/2019
0001 | T00005 | RAI______ | 16/01/2019______| 22/01/2019
0001 | T00006 | SCR_____ | 28/01/2019
0001 | T00007 | End______ | 28/01/2019
0002 | T00008 | Start_____ | 9/01/2018
0002 | T00009 | SCR_____ | 10/01/2018
0002 | T00010 | SD2C____ | 11/01/2018_______| 12/01/2019
0002 | T00011 | SCR_____ | 13/01/2019
0002 | T00012 | End______ | 13/01/2018
0003 | T00013 | Start_____ | 14/01/2018
0003 | T00014 | SD2C____ | 15/01/2018_______| 16/01/2018
0004 | T00015 | Start_____ | 16/01/2018
0004 | T00016 | SCR_____ | 17/01/2018
0004 | T00017 | SCR_____ | 18/01/2018
0004 | T00018 | SD2C____ | 19/01/2018_______| 30/01/2019
0004 | T00019 | RAI______ | 1/02/2019________| 2/02/2019
0004 | T00020 | SCR_____ | 2/02/2019
0004 | T00021 | End______ | 7/02/2019

TaskNr has unique Id

InfoRecDate only filled in when TaskDescr = (SD2C OR RAI) AND SR is closed (SR Contains Task description "End")

Expected Output:

- 1 Line per Closed SR -> SR contains a task with TaskDescr = "End"
- Latest InfoRecDate per closed SR
- SR Closed date (= TaskCreationDate of TaskDescr "End")

So something like this:
SR Number | "Latest" InfoRecDate | End Date

1 | 22/01/2019 | 28/01/2019

2 | 12/01/2019 | 13/01/2018

4 | 02/02/2019 | 07/02/2019

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the requirements down to two parts:

1. Get all rows where TaskDescr = 'End' (assuming there is always only one matching row per SRNr)
2. Look for the InfoRecDate for each of these SRNr

For part 2 I would use a subquery:

```
select 
  SRNr, 
  (select top 1 InfoRecDate from ServiceRequestTasks t2 
    where t1.SRNr = t2.SRNr and InfoRecDate is not null 
    order by InfoRecDate desc) as InfoDate, 
  TaskCreationDate 
from ServiceRequestTasks t1 
where TaskDescr = 'End'
```

I did not verify whether this works, but this is a fairly easy query - unless I missed something in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select SRNr,
       max(InfoRecDate) as latest_InfoRecDate,
       max(iif(TaskDescr = "End", TaskCreationDate, NULL)) as end_date
from t
group by SRNr
having sum(iif(TaskDescr = "End", 1, 0)) > 0;
```